# How to solve $ax+be^{cx}=d$

Tags: exponential-function, projectile-motion

Hi I have been trying to derive the formula for the range of a projectile with air resistance, and I've been trying to solve for time when $y=0$, and I have been left with an equation of the form $at+be^{ct}=d$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are constants. I can't seem to find a solution anywhere, but it must since the projectile obviously has to hit the ground.

Comment: There probably isn't a solution if you limit yourself to the basic arithmetic operations, square roots, trig functions, logs, etc. Most likely, there is a solution involving the Lambert-W function.

Answer (score 1):

An answer involving the [LambertW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function is $$x = -{1\over c}\,{\rm LambertW} \left(b c e^{cd/a} \over a\right) + {d\over a}.$$
(Maple.)